# How to retrive subtext from text from pdf document?

Tags: python

I have two functions: one for extracting text from scanned pdf document.

And one function for filtering specific text from the extracted text from the PDF document.

and so this method:  `get_text_from_image`

```
pdfFile = wi(filename="C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\python\\docs\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution=300)
text_factuur_verdi = []
ananas_crownless = 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'



def get_text_from_image(): 
    
    image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')
    imageBlobs = []
    
    for img in image.sequence:
        imgPage = wi(image=img)
        imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:        
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
        text_factuur_verdi.append(text)
        
    return text_factuur_verdi
```

returns the text from the PDF.

But now I want to have some specific text.

So I have this function:

```
def filterAnanas():
   return re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text_factuur_verdi)
```

and then I call it like this:

```
if ananas_crownless: print(filterAnans())
```

But then I get this error:

```
 File "C:\Python310\lib\re.py", line 247, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

question: how to improve this?

Thank you

if I do this:

```
for imgBlob in imageBlobs:        
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
        text_factuur_verdi.append(text)
        substring_ananas = re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text)
        return substring_ananas[0] if len(substring_ananas) > 0 else 'null'
```

it is working.

But of course I dont want that in the function get_text_from_image

retrived text:

```
08636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum : 19-11-21\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nOrder number : 76372 Loading date : 15-11-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK46\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\n566 Ananas 
Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I € 7,00 € 3.962,00\n706 Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I € 4,68 € 3.304,08\n598 Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 3.767,40\nOrder number : 76462 Loading date : 18-11-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK47\nD.C, Schoolfruit\n176 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 Generica UY Klasse I € 6,25 € 1.100,00\n179 Peen Waspeen 14x1kg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.127,70\n222 Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.398,60\n270 Peen Waspeen 14x1ikg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.701,00\nZuid\n176 sinaas\n222 wortel\nmidden\n270 wortel\nNoord\n179 wortel\nOrder number : 75674 Loading date : 18-11-21 Incoterm: 
: FRA\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK47\nD.C. Schoolfruit\n400 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER DE Klasse I € 4,70 € 1.880,00\n129 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER DE Klasse I € 4,70 € 606,30\n48 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 225,60\n104 = Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 488,80\n22 =Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 Viva IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 103,40\n107 ~=Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 Viva IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 502,90\n160 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 ALG ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 1.200,00\n6 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 ALG ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 45,00\n320 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 FVC ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 2.400,00\nREGIO\nSINAAS\nMIDDEN: 219\nNOORD: 267\nVerDi Import BV ING Bank N.V. Rotterdam IBAN number: NL17INGB0006959173 aoethe\nKoopliedenweg 38, 2991 LN Barendrecht, The Netherlands SWIFT/BIC: INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01\n\na\nTel. +31 (0)1 80 61 88 11, Fax +31 (0)1 80 61 88 25 Chamber of Commerce Rotterdam no. 55424309 VerDi\nE-mail: sales@verdiimport.nl, www.verdiimport.nl Dutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have 
exclusive jurisdiction.\n\nfrult and wegetadles\n\n \n\x0c', 'a> >)\n\nFactuur\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\nFactuur nr. : 70273 Koopliedenweg 38\nDeb. nr. : 108636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum ; 19-11-21\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nRETTICH:\nZUID: 216\nNOORD: 328\nMIDDEN: 266\nTotaal Colli Totaal Netto Btw Btw Bedrag Totaal Bedrag\n\n     \n \n\n€ 23.812,78 € 25.955,93\n\n   \n\nBetaling binnen 30 dagen\nAchterstand wordt gemeld bij de kredietverzekeringsmaatschappij\n\nVerDi Import BV ING Bank N.V. Rotterdam IBAN number: NL17INGBO006959173 =\nKoopliedenweg 38, 2991 LN Barendrecht, The Netherlands SWIFT/BIC: INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01 7\nTel. +31 (0)1 80 61 88 11, Fax +31 (0)1 80 61 88 25 Chamber of Commerce Rotterdam no. 55424309 VerD\nE-mail: sales@verdiimport.nl, www.verdiimport.nl Dutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction. l\n\nfrutt and vegetables:\n\n \n\x0c']
```

Comment: try this:`return re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), str(text_factuur_verdi))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But then I get empty list: []

Comment: But this works: print(get_text_from_image())

Comment: and if I do a    print(text_factuur_verdi) in the method: get_text_from_image then I see the extracted text

Comment: Can you edit your question with a piece of extracted text and your make_pattern function? If you're getting an empty list, it means there are no matches with your pattern

Comment: there is a match. But outside the function get_text_from_image the text_factuur_verdi is empty

Comment: But inside the function you're calling a single element, not the whole list, so text != text_factuur_verdi. Try with `return re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text_factuur_verdi[0])`, and if you have more than 1 element, just create an iterable. Hope it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248354/discussion-between-mightycode-newton-and-juan-federico).

Comment: return re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text_factuur_verdi[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: oke, but of course it is empty. Because I don't call first the method get_text_from_image if I call the method: filterAnanas()

Comment: ahhh, oke of course: def filterAnanas():
    get_text_from_image()        
    return re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text_factuur_verdi[0]) works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
def filterAnanas():
    get_text_from_image()        
    return re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text_factuur_verdi[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If we observe the signature of the `re.findall`, it is `findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`

In the above code,

> text_factuur_verdi

is a list object and `re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), text_factuur_verdi)` will definitely throw an error.

To make this work, we can convert the list object to string by using `str.join` as below.

`re.findall(make_pattern(ananas_crownless), ''.join(text_factuur_verdi))`